# Change name of \yii\imperavi\Widget widget

Tags: yii2

I want to change the name of the form field from Page[body] to body lets say. Following is the code for WYSIWYG editor.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(
                    \yii\imperavi\Widget::className(),
                    [
                        'plugins' => ['fontcolor', 'video'],
                        'options'=>[
                            'minHeight'=>400,
                            'maxHeight'=>400,
                            'buttonSource'=>true,
                            //'imageUpload'=>Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file-storage/upload-imperavi'])
                        ]
                    ]
                ) ?>
```

I don't want to change my model just the name of the form field submitted as the filed is submitted to remote API.

For normal fields i do `<?php echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['name' => 'name']) ?>`

Comment: are you saying that you dont want the name for the textarea that is generated by the widget to include model name?, if you dont want the model name to be the part of the field `name` then use the widget without the model instance see [here](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget/blob/master/src/Widget.php#L145) OR you can use a `FormModel` and declare your desired field names and use that formModel to create the ActiveForm

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes It can be done that way but I don't want to change my model. Isn't there a way to change the ID and NAME of the field without going for a work around?

Answer (score 0):

In the options you could assign an your name   value

```
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'body',  
                [ 'options' => [ 'name' => 'your_name']])->widget(
                        \yii\imperavi\Widget::className(),
                        [
                            'plugins' => ['fontcolor', 'video'],
                            'options'=>[
                                'minHeight'=>400,
                                'maxHeight'=>400,
                                'buttonSource'=>true,
                                //'imageUpload'=>Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file-storage/upload-imperavi'])
                            ]
                        ]
                    ) ?>
```

Comment: tried that, It should be that simple but the form submits as Page[body]: <p>abc</p>

Comment: I am submitting the form after serializing. Don't know what I miss here. :/

Comment: Sorry let me explain. I did what you suggested already but It doesn't change the name of the field. Even after doing what you suggested. <textarea id="w0" name="Page[body]" dir="ltr" style="display: none;"> is the html generated.

Comment: @FareedUdDin  answer  updated  assigning name the active field and not to the widget

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys this worked.

```
<?php
                    echo yii\imperavi\Widget::widget([
                        // You can either use it for model attribute
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'body',

                        // or just for input field
                        //'name' => 'body',
                        'htmlOptions'=>[
                            'name'=>'body',
                        ],
                        // Some options, see http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/
                        'options' => [
                            'toolbar' => false,
                        ],
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

and this also

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'body',  
                    [ 'options' => [ 'name' => 'body']])->widget(
                    \yii\imperavi\Widget::className(),
                    [
                        'plugins' => ['fontcolor', 'video'],
                        'htmlOptions'=>['name'=>'body'],
                        'options'=>[
                            'minHeight'=>400,
                            'maxHeight'=>400,
                            'buttonSource'=>true,
                            //'imageUpload'=>Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file-storage/upload-imperavi'])
                        ]
                    ]);?>
```